# Using OpenLayers 3 Feature onclick event?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, cartography

I looked for a way to fire onclick event and I found [Adding event handler to feature in OpenLayers 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26391195/how-to-add-event-handler-to-feature-in-open-layers-3) at Stack Overflow.  I undestand from this question is that there is no event onclick to features. I want to understand why is it? And maybe there is upcoming to the API and they have added a click events.

the way they offered to do it is like that:

```
map.on("click", function(e) {
    map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(e.pixel, function (feature, layer) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

It means i need to fire a click on the whole div map, then look for my specificPixel that the feature contains and then do whatever i want. It sounds primitive and will take too long for a high amount of features.

Is there another way to solve this problem?

Secondly, as i see there is no that much events on OpenLayers 3 api .
Why is it?

Answer (score 3):

> It means i need to fire a click on the whole div map, then look for my specificPixel that the feature contains and then do whatever i want.

I don't think you understand how forEachFeatureAtPixel works. Once you click, it takes the pixel clicked and iterate through all the layers to find any feature within a range of that pixel coordinate. It's not going through all the pixels of the map. Look at the code to better understand this. Further, it doesn't even iterate through "ALL" the features, it finds the features which are currently visible in the frame state. Alternatively, if you have too many features, You can divide your features to few layers and apply a layer filter too

> There is another way to solve this problem?

Yes, you can add a [select interaction](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.12.1/apidoc/ol.interaction.Select.html) to the map and use 'add' event on its feature collection.

```
var select_interaction = new ol.interaction.Select();

select_interaction.getFeatures().on("add", function (e) { 
     var feature = e.element; //the feature selected
});

map.addInteraction(select_interaction);
```

Comment: I'm not interested in on "add" event however i interested using the "click" can i use this event in this case , and how can i know which kind of events the api provides ? Secondly there is any built in function to popup feature ?

Comment: Individual features don't fire click events. So If you don't want to do this with interactions, the events fired from map is the only way I know. [Here](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.12.1/apidoc/ol.Map.html) you can see all the events fired from map.

Comment: For pop-ups you might find your answer [here](http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/measure.html). Look at the pointerMoveHandler

Comment: If i will add to every pixel any function that will take care of click event and i have about thousands features on thr viewport how much does it going to affects the performances ?

Comment: I don't think you understand how forEachFeatureAtPixel works. Once you click, it takes the pixel clicked and iterate through all the layers to find any feature intersects with the pixel coordinate. It's not going through all the pixels of the map. Look at the code to better understand this

Comment: Okay my point is that i will iterate all over the layers and my features and will find the one that intersects with the specific pixel it seem to be work in complexity of O(n) , can i use better way to find the specific feature that intersects the pixel maybe using QuadTree ?

Comment: The method we are talking about works pretty fast and if you really look at it, you'll see that it doesn't even iterate through "ALL" the features, it finds the features which are currently visible in the frame state. Alternatively, if you have too many features, You can divide your features to few layers and apply a layer filter too.

Comment: Nice so what you are saying that i can select specific layer to search on? And to manage the layers in way to decrease the complexity ?

Comment: Yes, [Here's](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/master/src/ol/renderer/maprenderer.js#L173) the code.

Comment: @itsyahani your comments should be part of your answer!